# Excel Macro Module blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have been having this problem for a while, all my macro codes just go blank and they don't function and excel crashes when I press the Macros button on the Developer toolbar. Tried searching everywhere but can't see something similar. When I click references, nothing happens. The only solution is to go back to an earlier version of the file. So I always save different versions of the same xlsm to prepared for when it crashes. Appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

[image: Blank Code]

Comment: Have you tried repairing/reinstalling Excel?

Comment: Yes, didn't help.